# How I debug about ERROR: connect ECONNRREFUSED?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, github, amazon-dynamodb, github-actions

I make a short-cut for my ***ci.yml***

```
jobs:
 test:
  runs-on: ubuntu-latest
  services:
    dynamodb: 
     image: amazon/dynamodb-local
     ports:
      - 8000:8000
    my-private-server:
     image: ghcr.io/myPrivateImage
     env:
      DYNAMODB_ENDPOINT: http://localhost:8000
     ports:
      - 80:80
  steps:
   - uses: actions/checkout@v3
   - uses: actions/setup-node@v3
   - run: npm ci
   - run: npm test
     env:
      DYNAMODB_ENDPOINT: http://localhost:8000 
      MY_PRIVATE_SERVICE_ENDPOINT: http://localhost:80
```

I have a private-server-container with `EXPOSE 80`, and I want to make it connected with local-dynamodb. My test is about loading some sample data into local-dynamodb first, and then my private-server will read these data from the local-dynamodb and return a value. But I always get the Error about ***" request to http://localhost/value?myQuery failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80"***

I think the problem maybe comes from the server container communication. But I am not sure. I would appreciate it if anyone could help.

Comment: "Connection refused" means that nothing's listening to the port that you're trying to connect to (in this case, 80). Look at the logs for your CI job, and you'll probably see an error starting `my-private-server`.

Comment: Thanks, but how do I check specific server container `my-private-server` logs in CI ? I check the CI logs really carefully, but I only found ***connect ECONNREFUSED*** in there.

Comment: Try `my-private-server.env.DYNAMODB_ENDPOINT: http://dynamodb:8000`?

Comment: Please write your solution to your problem as an answer. That way others can benefit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All right, after I try something else, I finally fix this problem. The solution is by running the job in the container. Here is https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-containerized-services/about-service-containers.

Here is code update.

```
jobs:
 test:
  runs-on: ubuntu-latest
  container: node:16-bullseye
  services:
    dynamodb: 
     image: amazon/dynamodb-local
    my-private-server:
     image: ghcr.io/myPrivateImage
     env:
      DYNAMODB_ENDPOINT: http://dynamodb:8000
  steps:
   - uses: actions/checkout@v3
   - uses: actions/setup-node@v3
   - run: npm ci
   - run: npm test
     env:
      DYNAMODB_ENDPOINT: http://dynamodb:8000 
      MY_PRIVATE_SERVICE_ENDPOINT: http://my-private-server:80
```